# How to make multi images with the same id in Laravel 7

Tags: laravel-7

I'm making a product image upload form which results in many images belonging to one product id. How do I do that?

For uploading multiple images, it has been successful, but the product id is still separate.

This my controller:

```
public function store(ProductRequest $request,$id) {
    if ($request->hasFile('photo')){

        $photos = $request->file('photo');

        foreach ($photos as $photo) {

            $data= $request->all();

            $data['slug'] = Str::slug($request->name);
            $product=Product::create($data);

            $uploadphoto = [
                'products_id' => $product->id,
                'photos' => $photo->store('assets/product','public')
            ];
             ProductGallery::create($uploadphoto);
        }
    }else{
        return "image not found";
    }

    return redirect()->route('dashboard-product');

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating product inside of foreach that will create multiple products. If you need only one product keep the code of creating product, outside of foreach.

```
public function store(ProductRequest $request,$id) {
    if ($request->hasFile('photo')){
        
        $photos = $request->file('photo');

        $data= $request->all();

        $data['slug'] = Str::slug($request->name);
        $product=Product::create($data);



        foreach ($photos as $photo) {
            $uploadphoto = [
                'products_id' => $product->id,
                'photos' => $photo->store('assets/product','public')
            ];
             ProductGallery::create($uploadphoto);
        }



    }else{
        return "image not found";
    }      
    
    return redirect()->route('dashboard-product');

}
```